# SwiftUI ObservableObject CPU spikes

Tags: performance, swiftui

I have a SwiftUI project and a View that binds to an EnvironmentObject. This object contains a @Published property.

```
import Foundation

class Global : ObservableObject{

    @Published var check :Bool = false;

}
```

When I run the application and make changes to my property, I see that my view gets redrawn on every change.

```
import SwiftUI
import Combine


struct ContentView: View {

    @EnvironmentObject var global :Global

    var body: some View {
        VStack{
        VStack{
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
        Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)


        }
        VStack{
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)


            }
        VStack{
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)


            }
        VStack{
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)
            Toggle("Checked", isOn: $global.check)


            }
        }
    }
}
```

CPU rates get near 15%, just to draw 20 checkboxes. Is there something I am doing wrong or are there other ways to improve performance? I don't want to use a debounce to resolve this.

**Extra information**
MacOS Catalina 10.15.2 running MacOS SwiftUI project in XCode 11.3

Attached is an Instrument profiling of me clicking and unclicking one of my checkboxes every second. In Instruments I even see CPU run op to 90%.

[image]

Comment: I do not observe this neither for iOS nor for macOS, ~1% in maximum. How did you test it? In which environment? More details please.

Comment: Please see my updates. I can also share my test project with you if you want

Comment: I use Xcode 11.2... too many bugs reported for 11.3 to migrate.

Comment: I tried 11.2 and got the same results. Its when you click rapidly

Comment: I've run this on the simulator and iPhone 7. CPU hit 25% on the phone when toggling rapidly. Same result if I change global to be a struct and @State. I don't believe this is unreasonable CPU usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SwiftUI views get redrawn when @ObservedObject, @EnvironmentObject, @StateObject or @State change. If you use so many toggles that bind to the same property, then you would expect a higher CPU usage. You aren't doing anything wrong and there is no way to improve performance of it for your purpose other than wait for improvements to SwiftUI itself.